# How to return only native methods using PHP ReflectionAPI?

Tags: php, inheritance, reflection, methods, native-methods

I am pretty new to PHP. I am trying to use Php's Reflection API to return ONLY the methods from the native class (which is the only class in the file).  Right now it returns all the methods from this class and the class it extends. I can't call `isAbstract()` on it because the class I am extending is an abstract class.

```
<?php
class Controller extends \Base\Controller

$rc = new ReflectionClass($strFullClass);
foreach ($rc->getMethods() as $method) {
    $strMethod = $method->getName();
    echo $method;
}
```

This returns:

```
Method [ <user> public method keywordPerformance ] {
  @@ /AdwordIntegration/Controller.php 28 - 31

  - Parameters [4] {
    Parameter #0 [ <required> $campaign_id ]
    Parameter #1 [ <required> $adgroup_id ]
    Parameter #2 [ <required> $start_date ]
    Parameter #3 [ <required> $stop_date ]
  }
}

Method [ <user, inherits \Base\Controller> protected method formValidationError ] {
  @@ /Base/Controller.php 26 - 29

  - Parameters [1] {
    Parameter #0 [ <required> $result ]
 }
}
```

How do I get Reflection to ignore inherited methods?

Comment: `if ($rc->getDeclaringClass !== $strFullClass)`?

Comment: I can't call `getDeclaringClass()` on a reflection class, but it will allow me to call it on `$method`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Fixed my comment: `if ($method->getDeclaringClass() !== $strFullClass) {...}`